# How can use policy function with middleware in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, middleware, policy

I used middleware by defining a function in policy like below:

in UserPolicy.php:

```
    public function accessUser(User $user)
    {
        return $user->inRole('admin');
    }

    public function manageUser(User $user, User $secondUser)
    {
        return $user->inRole('admin') || $secondUser->id === $user->id;
    }
```

in UserController.php:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('can:accessUser', ['except' => ['show']]);
}

public function index(Request $request)
{
    ...
}

public function show(Request $request, User $user)
{   
    $this->authorize('manageUser', $user);
    ...
}
```

I am using `admin` account. It works for `show` function but does not work for `index` function. why?? what shall I do? Is there any other place that I should define `accessUser` function?

Answer (score 0):

Also, should send Model to policy via middleware..

```
 public function __construct()
 {
     $this->middleware('can:accessUser, App\Models\User', ['except' => ['show']]);
 }
```

It's working well :)